# Validate html tags in json file using java - whats the best way?

Tags: java, html

Is there a java library, java framework, or java example that I could supply a URL, www.test.com/storage/test.json, and validate that HTML elements, specifically HTML opening and closing tags, so I can be sure when changes are made to the json file, the web page ( www.test.com/content) that reads the content will still render?

As for a little background, I can be considered a novice when it comes to java development.  I am looking to create a automated script which will be ran via jenkins to validate a json file.  So far, I have been able to identify placeholders and verify they are not blank, and/or are only numeric for example.  I have even been able to identify any type of links that may sit in the json file and make sure they are valid by using java.net.HttpURLConnection.  My next goal is to validate HTML tags are properly formatted.

Thank you

Edit/example of json file:

```
    {"list":[{

    "type":"example",

    "id":"123",

    "body": "<p><i>text</i></p>
```

Comment: I am a little confused. You say you want to "validate a json file" and you also say you want to "and validate HTML elements" which is it?

Comment: Could you supply an example of what you want to validate.

Comment: @bhspencer example added above, thanks

Comment: Personally I would consider not including html inside your JSON data structure. JSON is really for data not for layout and formatting. Instead you should only include data in the JSON and then with javascript in the browser dynamically create the DOM elements you need.

Comment: @bhspencer, thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately, no control over that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what you want to do, but if your question is about a library to validate HTML elements coming from a string in Java, the two I would suggest are [jcabi-w3c validator](http://w3c.jcabi.com/html-validator.html) and the [Nu HTML5 Validator](http://validator.github.io/validator/).

They should play well in validating your HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate body field containing HTML content by adding following to your JSON schema:

```
{
    "body": {
        "type": "string",
        "media": {
            "type": "text/html"
        }
    }
}
```